# How to disable a submit button until other button has been pressed?

Tags: forms, jsf, button, submit, confirm

I have a simple JSF form:

```
<h:form>
   <h:inputText value="#{textBean.firstName}"/>
   <h:inputText value="#{textBean.lastName}"/>
   <h:commandButton value="confirm" action="textBean.confirm"/>
   <h:commandButton value="submit" action="textBean.submit"/>
</h:form>
```

It is necessary that before you click "submit" user must press the button "confirm". Otherwise, next to the button  "submit" display an error message. A user can not click the submit button, if not pre-pressed to confirm. It is very desirable to do it on a layer of the UI. Some might suggest something about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to change the logic so that on click of the submit button a confirmation dialog box is presented to the user. Something simple like this:

```
<h:form>
   <h:inputText value="#{textBean.firstName}"/>
   <h:inputText value="#{textBean.lastName}"/>
   <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{textBean.submit}" onclick="return confirm('Confirm form submit?');"/>
</h:form>
```

Otherwise if you want to get the behaviour mentioned above you could disable / hide the submit button until the user has clicked the confirm button, something like:

```
<h:form>
   <h:inputText value="#{textBean.firstName}"/>
   <h:inputText value="#{textBean.lastName}"/>
   <h:commandButton value="confirm" action="#{textBean.confirm}"/>
   <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{textBean.submit}" disabled="#{textBean.btnDisabled}"/>
</h:form>
```

The disabled attribute can be replaced with the rendered attribute if you want to hide the button. It takes a boolean. This boolean variable can be set in your confirm method to true so that when the request comes back the button will be enabled.